# Calling a function makes UThash to fail

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am using the hash-table implementation UThash.

I am inserting elements using the primitive:

```
    HASH_ADD(hh,hash_table,key,keylen,elem);
```

And retrieving elements with the primitive:

```
    HASH_FIND(hh,hash_table,key,keylen,elem);
```

For some reason I don't know, the behaviour of hash find is being modified when I call a function. That is to say, **uthash does not find an element that is present in the table**.

I suspect memory has been compromised in some way.

The function that triggers this failure **does not need to execute any code** to make UThash fail:

```
    //Note: ct = custom_type
    int func1(ct1 *ptr1, ct2 *ptr2, ct3 *ptr3,char **buffer,size_t *size)
    {
       HASH_FIND(...) //does not work

       /**
        * code
        */
        return 0;
    }

    int func2(ct1 *ptr1,ct2 *ptr2,ct3 *ptr3)
    {
        char *buffer;
        size_t buf_size;

       /**
        * code
        */

        HASH_FIND(...) // works!
        if(func1(ptr1,ptr2,ptr3,&buffer,&buf_size)){
            //code
        }/*error*/

        return 0;
    }

    int func3(ct1 *ptr1,ct2 *ptr2,ct3 *ptr3)
    {
        char *buffer;
        size_t buf_size;

        HASH_FIND(...) // works!
        if(func1(ptr1,ptr2,ptr3,&buffer,&buf_size)){
            //code
        }/*error*/

        /**
         * code
         */

        return 0;
    }
```

So in both *func2()* and *func3()* the same behaviour happens. hash_find() starts to fail after I call  *func1()*.

*All the rest of the code is executed perfectly and correctly.*

**My obvious question is what could cause such type of failure?**

Thank you for reading and be free to ask any additional info.

Answer (score 2):

This can be caused by adding several items with the same key into hash. If you use uthash, you need to make sure that you don't have duplicated keys in your structure, or to provide a wrapper function which will substitute an old item with the new one. Otherwise, the behaviour of the structure is unpredictable and can cause the failure you described.

From [uthash user guide](http://uthash.sourceforge.net/userguide.html):

> If there’s any chance that duplicate keys could be generated by your
>   program, you must explicitly check the uniqueness before adding the
>   key to the hash. If the key is already in the hash, you can simply
>   modify the existing structure in the hash rather than adding the item.
>   It is an error to add two items with the same key to the hash table.

Comment: Rather an old question, but it seems I have ran into the exact same issue. I know that there are no multiple items with the same key (checked and verified when building the hash table), yet calling the `HASH_FIND` function fails inside another function. I have been scratching my head for a day now trying to figure out why. I can even locate the key by simply iterating over the entire table, yet FIND fails to do the same! Any clue what could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are hashing the pointer not the data.

Use [HASH_ADD_KEYPTR](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html#_string_keys).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, when my key had type **unsigned char**,
after replacing it with **int** HASH_FIND_INT started to work properly. Further investiation showed that bother **signed char** and **unsigned char** are not appropriate, whereas **short int** and **unsigned short int** seem to work fine as well.

Probably 8 bits are not enough for hash function calculation algorithm to operate properly.
Notice, that original code with **unsigned char** operation was intermittent, code worked in some builds, did not work in others (with changes unrelated to uthash).

Conclusion: use key of type **signed int** for proper operation of HASH_FIND_INT, or use **short int** or **unsigned short** at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it's not the case, but I have encountered similar problem when I used some `struct` as a key for `HASH_FIND`. Beware of `struct` padding when you use `sizeof()` to determine key length. If you don't initialize a key properly this padding may be the reason why `uthash` does not find when you lookup.

Comment: @MLavoie: This does appear to be an attempt to answer the OP's question.  It is not requesting clarification from the OP.  I do not think it should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem because of `struct` padding, as mentioned by @yerden.  On gcc it is easy, but slow, to define the `struct` with the packed attribute, as

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) a_struct {
    char a, b;
    unsigned int i;
};
```

This problem is mentioned in the [uthash manual](https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html#_structure_keys) for structure keys, and the solution is to zero out the `struct` before adding it to the hash, as demonstrated there.

Another solution is to [learn about structure packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/) and reorganize your `struct` so padding is not (or less of) an issue.  A quick overview of structure packing is given in another helpful [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing).